# How to select a column from 1 table and a column from another table given info in the first table

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

So I have a table Item, itemPicked and person. And here is my code. I want to pick out the names of people who picked shoe (item_id 2) and at what time they did that. Sorry for my mistakes as I started learning sql only a few days now. Or if there was something similar but I did not know how to ask properly how to find it.

My expected output should be :

person8 04/05/2003
person9 01/11/2011

```
CREATE TABLE item(
itemid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
item_name TEXT );

CREATE TABLE itemPicked(
person_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
item_id INTEGER,
picked_at TEXT);

CREATE TABLE person(
personid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
person_name TEXT);
INSERT INTO item
VALUES
        (1, 'box'),
        (2, 'shoe'),
        (3, 'flower');

INSERT INTO itemPicked
VALUES
    (8, 2, '04/05/2003),
    (9, 2, '01/11/2001'),
    (10, 1, '11/11/2011');

INSERT INTO person
VALUES
    (1, 'person1'),
    (2, 'person2'),
    (3, 'person3'),
    (4, 'person4'),
    (5, 'person5'),
    (6, 'person6'),
    (7, 'person7'),
    (8, 'person8'),
    (9, 'person9'),
    (10, 'person10');
```

Comment: Look up "MySQL JOIN" in Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQL Joins to join the two tables

```
SELECT p.person_name, i.picked_at 
  FROM person AS P
  INNER JOIN itemPicked AS i 
  ON i.person_id = p.personid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked and I hope to solve the rest of my problems now :). Only thing is, you missed a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Simple JOIN will do the trick

```
select 
  p.person_name,
  ip.picked_at 
from person p
join itemPicked ip on p.personid = ip.person_id
where ip.item_id = 2;
```

Comment: Yours only showed the first thing in the list for some reason.

Comment: I don't think so as you can see results here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99dab/3
btw you have an error in values in itemPicked (missing closing ')